# Max value of random variable that's uniformly disturbuted

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

If $x_i$ where $i \in [1,6]$ are random independent variables of uniform distribution in $(0,1)$. I need to compute $P[\sum_{i=1}^{6}x_i<18]$ .

The writer says:

We have the max value when $x_i=1\, \forall i$ . Then , the max value of $\sum_{i=1}^{6}x_i=6$ hence : $P = 1$.

I was wondering **where does that max value comes from?**

I computed : $E[x_i]=\frac12$ and $Var(x_i) = \frac1{12}$.

Comment: Uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, presumably.  Then $1$ is the maximum possible value and $0$ is the minimum.  But you do need to specify the interval.

Comment: you are right they are distirbuted in (0,1)

Comment: @RobertIsrael how we know that it can take the value 1?

Comment: More precisely, the supremum of possible values is $1$.  Whether the actual value $1$ is allowed or not is not really relevant (these are continuous random variables, so the probability of $x_i = 1$ is $0$ in any case).

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_i \in U[0,1]$, $x_i$ can only take values between $0$ and $1$. In other words, the probability that $x_i$ is **not** between $0$ and $1$ is $0$.

$$P(x_i >1) = 0\quad P(x_i <0) = 0$$

Hence, when you add up $6$ numbers that are between $0$ and $1$, their sum can be $6$ at the most.

Comment: mm is it $P(x_i>1) = 1 - P(x_i<=1)  = 1 - \int_{0}^{1} {f_{x_i} dx}=1-\int_{0}^{1} {1dx} = 1 - 1 = 0 $ and $P(xi<0) = \int_{0}^{0} 1dx = 0?$

Comment: Well, that's one way of doing it. Either way, $f_{x_i} = 1$ for $x_i \in [0,1]$ and is $0$ everywhere else. $P(x_i<0) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^0 f_{x_i} dx = 0$.